# Azure Machine Learning Service - Environment variables defined in Environment not accessible from init() method in entry_script

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am deploying a model to AKS via AML using the python-sdk, and I am facing a problem accessing the environment variables defined for the `Environment` object `myenv`used for the deployment.

```
# add environment variable
myenv.environment_variables = {'SOME_ENV_VARIABLE': 'ABC'}
# register to workspace
myenv.register(ws)
```

This environment object is stated in the inference configuration for the deployment:

```
myenv = Environment.get(workspace=ws,name="myenv")
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py',
                                      source_directory=os.path.abspath(__file__ + "//.."),
                                      environment=myenv,
                                      enable_gpu=True,
                                      description="...")
```

When the model executes, the init() method in the entry_script `score.py` should be able to access these environment variables by calling `os.environ['SOME_ENV_VARIABLE']`. However, that is not working. The conda and pip packages defined in `myenv` are present in the image.

Shouldn't it be possible to access these env variables from the entry_script?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer in case some people wonder how to pass environment variables that with Managed Endpoint in SDKv2.

In SDKv2, if you are deploying to a Managed Endpoint, you can pass the environment variables to the ManagedOnlineDeployment object. See below:

```
model_deployment = ManagedOnlineDeployment(
    name=deploy_name,
    endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
    description="My Deployment.",
    model=model_asset,
    environment=deploy_env,
    code_configuration=CodeConfiguration(
        code=os.path.join(scripts_dir, "scripts"),
        scoring_script="score.py"),
    instance_type="Standard_DS4_v2",
    instance_count=1,
    environment_variables={'my_env': 'my_value'}, # pass environment variables to the score.py
)
```

In score.py:

```
# Called when the service is loaded
def init():
    global model
    print(os.getenv("my_env")) # my_value in the logs
```

Comment: Your answer made my day today.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables set on environment object are deprecated. Those are runtime variables set during the execution and implementation moved to the RunConfiguration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.runconfig.runconfiguration?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-runconfig-runconfiguration-environment-variables

Variables baked into the image could be set in the dockerfile of the environment or in your base image.
Sorry if some of the docs are misleading, we are working on fixing those.

Comment: RunConfiguration object is used for Pipeline runs, usually when training. Web Services use InferenceConfig and AksServiceDeploymentConfiguration. As a consequence, it is not possible to set the environment variables for Web Services using the AML SDK. It is unfortunate that a custom Docker image must therefore be created to use environment variables for inference.

Comment: I used the deployment.yml to set environment variables and it worked for me. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-custom-container#create-a-yaml-file-for-your-endpoint-and-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment by instantiating Environment object and then setting its attributes: set of Python packages, environment variables and others.

**Specify environment variables:**

myenv.environment_variables = {"MESSAGE":"Hello from Azure Machine Learning"}

You can add environment variables to your environment. These then become available using os.environ.get in your training script.

Please follow the below for using environments for inferencing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I'm doing exactly as you describe, and still, I'm not able to access the environment variables in the inference script, score.py

Comment: PR raised to fix this known issue, will update further on this.

Comment: Fix is deployed.

Comment: hmm, I still cannot access the environmental variables from the score.py script in my deployed model. And if I 'docker exec -it .../bin/bash' on a locally deployed model container, none of the registered environmental variables are present. The envs are shown when I inspect environment using 'Environment.get(workspace, name)'. Any suggestions to what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Same thing here. Env vars are just not set. Neither accessible in score.py, nor inside a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested environment_variables from an Environment ojb. It works. I also included a couple of environment variables for an inference environment.

python sdk v1.38.0.

The solution I used more or less the same as what was described above. After model was deployed in ACI, the environment variables are visible from properties (Containers -> Properties) e.g., [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioMDs.png)

Comment: Use of Environment.environment_variables is deprecated (see @vizhur's answer).